# NX project generator - Omit installing nx-plugin package

Tags: nrwl-nx, probot, nx-generator

I'm trying to build an NX generator to generate a Probot app inside an NX workspace. But when I'm using the generator, for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
PS C:\repos\testjews> nx generate @mintplayer/nx-generators:create-probot-app --verbose

 >  NX   Unable to resolve @mintplayer/nx-generators:create-probot-app.

   Cannot find module '@mintplayer/nx-generators/package.json'
   Require stack:
   - C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\src\utils\package-json.js
   - C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\src\utils\package-manager.js
   - C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\bin\init-local.js
   - C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js
   - C:\Users\Pieterjan De Clippel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js

Error: Unable to resolve @mintplayer/nx-generators:create-probot-app.
Cannot find module '@mintplayer/nx-generators/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\src\utils\package-json.js
- C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\src\utils\package-manager.js
- C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\bin\init-local.js
- C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js
- C:\Users\Pieterjan De Clippel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js
    at getGeneratorInformation (C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\generate\generator-utils.js:39:15)
    at C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\src\command-line\generate\generate.js:218:248
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async handleErrors (C:\repos\testjews\node_modules\nx\src\utils\params.js:9:16)
```

Apparently there's a `package.json` file that cannot be found.

These are the commands I ran to get to the current [project containing the generators](https://github.com/MintPlayer/nx-plugins):

```
npx create-nx-workspace
> mintplayer-nx-plugins
> None
> Package-based monorepo
cd mintplayer-nx-plugins
npm i @nx/plugin@latest
nx g @nx/plugin:plugin nx-generators
code .
cd nx-generators
nx generate @nx/plugin:generator create-probot-app
> Derived
```

Additional resources:

- [Documentation](https://nx.dev/extending-nx/recipes/local-generators)
- [The NX js generators](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/tree/master/packages/js/src/generators)
- [The NX angular generators](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/tree/master/packages/angular/src/generators)

### Edit

It seems that when I first install the package manually

```
npm i @mintplayer/nx-generators
```

then run the generator

```
nx generate @mintplayer/nx-generators:create-probot-app
```

everything works as expected. But is there a way to omit the manual installation of this library, and let `nx generate` handle that for me?

Comment: try running `npm i` to install all the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks that doesn't solve it. But you gave me a clue. When I first manually install the package `npm i @mintplayer/nx-generators`, then run the command, everything works as expected. But afaik this shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: So, If this is the first time you use the library, I think you have to install it globally then you can skip installing it and running the generator directly. To install it globally you need to run `npm i -g @mintplayer/nx-generators` to have the lib installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finished creating an [NX Plugin with a Probot generator](https://github.com/MintPlayer/nx-plugins).